# React/Redux: how to call an API after getting data from the browser?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux

My React app is supposed to display nearby shops to each user depending on their location.

What I'm trying to do is to get the latitude/longitude by `window.geolocation` in the `componentDidMount()` in which I'll call a REST API with the latitude/longitude as params to retrieve nearby shops.

I'm just trying to figure out how to organize and where to put the logic.

Comment: if you want to call an API when you first load the site you can call `componentDidMount`. If you want to call it after you update the data you can use `componentDidUpdate`. You will be using `Fetch` or `axios` to make the ajax call.

Comment: Usually you will be using `mapDispatchToProps` to map the method `SomeActionDispatcher` you want to use in `componentDidMount` to props in the container. `SomeActionDispatcher` is responsible for dispatching actions.

Comment: Asynchronous actions can be handled in redux middleware, you can use [redux-thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk) for that so you can dispatch an action that will call a function that will get geo, dispatch action with geo info, get nearby shops, when resolved dispatch an action with the shops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is that you should try to use React's state before reaching for redux. It's both simpler and keeps as much of the state local as possible.

The React state stores the status of the API call (not made yet, success or failure) and the corresponding information about success (`results`) or failure (`errorMessage`). The important point is that your `render` function must explicitly handle all 3 cases.

```js
class NearbyShops extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      queryStatus: 'initial',
      results: [],
      errorMessage: '',
    }
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    try {
      const results = await fetch('you.api.url/here');
      this.setState(prevState => ({...prevState, results, queryStatus: 'success'}))
    } catch (e) {
      this.setState(prevState => ({...prevState, queryStatus: 'failure', errorMessage: e}))
    }
  }

  render() {
    const {results, queryStatus, errorMessage} = this.state;

    if (queryStatus === 'success') {
      return (
        <div>{/* render results here */}</div>
      )
    } else if (queryStatus === 'failure') {
      return (
        <div>{errorMessage}</div>
      )
    } else {
      return (
        <div>Loading nearby shops...</div>
      )
    }
  }
}
```